# Using SpringRestGraphDatabase API to work within transaction

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm new to graph db and i'm having problems to get the api work within a transaction.

I have a simple code that uses the neo4j graph db api to create nodes and relationship. My code runs in JUnit and tries to create 2 nodes and a relationship between them using begin and end transaction given below.

The code works fine in a happy scenario. However, if something fails within the code, the nodes are still committed into the graph database. Not sure if i'm doing something wrong out here. I would have expected the 2 nodes created to be rolled back.

Here is the code snippet:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext.xml" })
public class RestBatchLoaderTest {  

    @Autowired
    SpringRestGraphDatabase graphDatabaseService;

@Test
public void createNode() {
    Transaction tx =graphDatabaseService.beginTx();

    try {
        Map<String,Object> nodeprops1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        nodeprops1.put("name", "James Parker");
        nodeprops1.put("age", Integer.valueOf(11));
        Node james = graphDatabaseService.createNode(nodeprops1);           
        Assert.assertNotNull(james);

        Map<String,Object> nodeprops2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        nodeprops2.put("name", "Bing P");
        nodeprops2.put("age", Integer.valueOf(34));
        Node bing= graphDatabaseService.createNode(nodeprops2);

        Node aa = null;
                    // Failure point: should rollback the previous node in the finally.
        graphDatabaseService.remove(aa);            


        Map<String,Object> relprops = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        RelationshipType type = new RelationshipType() {

            @Override
            public String name() {
                return "MARRIED_TO";
            }
        };
        graphDatabaseService.createRelationship(joe, jane, type, relprops);
        tx.success();

    } finally {
        tx.finish();
    }
}
```

The **graphDatabaseService** object is autowired using spring configuration. Here is the configuration:

```xml
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/"/>
</bean>
```

Also, I notice **tx** object is an instance of *NullTransaction* when **graphDatabaseService.beginTx()** is called in the code above.

Any ideas, what is going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think figured out what the problem was. The configuration needs to have batch enabled - true. Also i used the RestAPI wrapper to the graph database object to run it as one atomic code. See code below:

```
@Autowired
SpringRestGraphDatabase graphDatabaseService;

private RestAPI restAPI;

@Before
public void init(){
    this.restAPI = ((RestGraphDatabase)graphDatabaseService).getRestAPI();
}

@Test
public void testEnableBatchTransactions() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty(Config.CONFIG_BATCH_TRANSACTION,"true");
    Transaction tx = restAPI.beginTx();
    try {
        Node n1 = restAPI.createNode(map("name", "node1"));
        Node n2 = restAPI.createNode(map("name", "node2"));
        Node n3 = restAPI.createNode(map("name", "node3"));
        //String s = null;
        //s.toString();
        Node n4 = restAPI.createNode(map("name", "node4"));      
        tx.success();
    } finally {
         tx.finish();
    }


    assertTrue(tx instanceof BatchTransaction);
}
```

Also `System.setProperty(Config.CONFIG_BATCH_TRANSACTION,"true");` enables the batch mode.

To test this, try un-commenting the code snippet and run the test. Nodes *n1*, *n2* and *n3* will not be committed in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You specified `graphDatabaseService.remove(aa);` as your failure point as `aa` is `NULL`. Looking into the documentation of `org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase` there is no `Exception` documented that is being thrown if the node is `NULL`. Have you verified that an exception is actually thrown? Otherwise your code will run through to `tx.success();`. If an exception is thrown, please specify further what version of neo4j and spring you are using.

---

**Edit:**

After reading a little more, I see in the source of `org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase` that it should give you a `NullTransaction` that basically does nothing (see [here](https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/blob/f73b6473a130214c379cd0c4f04ae5ddb1fd5e95/src/main/java/org/neo4j/rest/graphdb/transaction/NullTransaction.java)).
Furthermore, the `Spring Data neo4j documentation`states that each operation is in its own transaction as the neo4j REST adapter does not allow transaction that span over multiple operations (see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#d5e2018)).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess that makes it clear why my nodes were being created in the graph (before the exception was thrown). Is there a way to create nodes and relationship in within a transaction. I want to import a bunch of data into the graph. I have read on rest batch api and csv. Is that the only way to create nodes and relationship as one atomic unit?

Comment: You could use neo4j in the embedded mode: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#d5e620

Comment: I think figured out what the problem was. The configuration needs to have batch enabled - true. Also i used the RestAPI wrapper to the graph database object to run it as one atomic code. See code below: